# How to get json structure in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

my application should sent structure via json,
that functions works fine:

```
function send_json()
{
    var formData = form2object('myForm');
    var json_data = JSON.stringify(formData, null, '\t');
    $.post("", json_data);
}
```

It create json_data and send it via post.
But I don't understand how to catch this data on another side, can you help me ?
I should take this structure and make some actions with it.

when i send data i got json:

```
{ "type": "test", "ttl": "1", "amount": "1", "rules": { "rule1": "1", "value1": "4444", "stackcount1": "1", "rule2": "2", "value2": "333", "stackcount2": "2" }}
```

In the contoller i wrote this:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @json_string = params[:amount]
    if !@json_sting.nil?
      @json_string = JSON.parse(params[:amount])
    end
  end
end
```

in the view(haml) i wrote:

```
=@json_string
```

It doesn't work !

But wireshark shows:

```
POST /admin/ HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: ru-ru,ru;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost:3000/admin/
Content-Length: 192
Cookie: _GiftSenderTool_session=BAh7BzoQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMTVyNVJCMTBvcGpKSk5OcFN4bW15YVlpRlF1TUNtb1gwZkY0bTRuRHlsNnM9Ig9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiU4ZjFjNTNjNTY0MTQ1MGExNmFiODcxZGEyYzU5ZTkxMg%3D%3D--f21bf3b96edc3bc551c8de68acc6da17685d58b4
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache

{
."type": "test",
."ttl": "1",
."amount": "1",
."rules": {
.."rule1": "1",
.."value1": "4444",
.."stackcount1": "1"
.},
."authenticity_token": "n3B6D/Km9zOgOzlosK/OLHyTCDLk3MyCTlTBinfQcnY="
}
```

It means that i can't get data.

Comment: You probably want to use ```respond_to``` with ```format.json```. Read this [ASCIICast about controllers](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3).

Comment: @mrzasa, sounds like he wants to read json in his Rails app, not output it.

Comment: I made variable in json format and i sent this json to the same page(doesn't matter, i could sent it to another page).

How should I take this json in page ?

Some actions, actions which i can do with data, everything.
I can put it to database or put to view.

Of course I wrote about rails, i set tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to catch your JSON object in some rails controller action. If your JSON string looks like this:

```
{ "user": { "id": 1, "name": "Tom" } }
```

then do it like this:

```
require "json"
...
def some_action
  user = JSON.parse(params[:user])
  puts "User id is #{user[:id]}"
  ...
end
```